# postgresql Looping through JSONB array and performing SELECTs

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have jsonb in one of my table

the jsonb looks like this

```
my_data : [
     {pid: 1, stock: 500},   
     {pid: 2, stock: 1000},
     ...
]
```

pid refers to `products`' table `id` ( which is `pid` )

EDIT: The table products has following properties: `pid` (PK), `name`

I want to loop over `my_data[]` in my JSONB and fetch `pid`'s name from product table.

I need the result to look something like this (including the product names from the second table) ->

```
my_data : [ 
       { 
          product_name : "abc", 
          pid: 1, 
          stock : 500 
       },
       ...
]
```

How should I go about performing such jsonb inner join?

Edit :- tried S-Man's solutions and i'm getting this error

> "invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"jc\""

here is the 
[SQL QUERY](https://pastebin.com/0HTGWGz7)

Comment: Your question states that you have jsonb value and you want a jsonb output. But fetching pid and product... It is quite confusing. What are you expecting?

Comment: @S-Man  I have a main table which as a jsonb property. That jsonb property is my_data  ( array ). This array of object has pid which references to another table name 'Products'. So i need to perform a query which can connect pid with name and give me the desired output. The query in question is executed on the main table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=91615c5ff9480c64e1c686b4864fc756)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(                                                            -- 5
        'my_data',
        jsonb_agg(                                                                 -- 4
             elems || jsonb_build_object('product_name', mot.product_name)         -- 3
        )
    )
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'my_data') as elems                              -- 1
JOIN
    my_other_table mot ON (elems ->> 'pid')::int = mot.pid                          -- 2
```

1. Expand JSON array into one row per array element
2. Join the other table against the current one using the pid values (notice the `::int` cast, because otherwise it would be text value)
3. The new columns from the second table now can be converted into a JSON object. This one can be concatenate onto the original one using the `||` operator
4. After that recreating the array from the array elements again
5. Putting this in array into a `my_data` element

---

Another way is using `jsonb_set()` instead of step 5 do reset the array into the original array directly:

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6ebfc80d1d559f8533ecb7eee4b9da31)

```
SELECT
   jsonb_set(
       mydata,
       '{my_data}',
       jsonb_agg(
            elems || jsonb_build_object('product_name', mot.product_name)
       )
   )
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(mydata -> 'my_data') as elems
JOIN
    my_other_table mot ON (elems ->> 'pid')::int = mot.pid
GROUP BY mydata
```

Comment: my jsonb array conntains only the pid which is the foreign key to  products table pid. So i need to perform a  join query in order to gain the product_name column

Comment: Changed, added step-by-step demo fiddle

Comment: Added a second way

Comment: WOW ty for your quick reply. Really appreciated.


Also for second case , if i had multiple nested array.


For example :-
[ { heading: 'test', pItems: [{ pid: 5,stock 500 }] } ]

How would you unnest multiple arrays ?

Comment: If you have only one element at the top the first case, otherwise you have to expand two array with the same function (second case): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4472d848c2a55a13403311f26e276999

Comment: Btw: With Postgres 12 you can simply get all pid values using jsonpath: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cc1973fb048b17add28a2527b86a7046

Comment: Yes by all means. Thank you so much for your quick help ! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried your solution. And i'm getting this error 
"invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"jc\""

Here is the query dump

https://pastebin.com/0HTGWGz7

Comment: my bad.. new to these things.

Comment: Yes, but please try to create a fiddle which reproduces the problem (see my answers). Without any data or debugging possibilities it is quite hard to find errors in your query. I cannot see something obvious scanning your code

Comment: here is the way to recreate it
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b71d7d9d01631030aa3c3e2c8d3f8e9b

Comment: mainTable has no client_id

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the keys. But the same error would persist no matter what. On my real world DB i do have every property in place 

Updated the code 

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=63e5b8a49940bb50b5bb7985a947c09e

Comment: oh yes !! by all means. Thank you so much!

Comment: how to map the final nested result ? 
I want something like this :- https://pastebin.com/i71EkRan

I'm getting this error 
aggregate function calls cannot be nested

fiddle :-

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d2bcd27df11fd13ffe1da0da135ac60d

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a5f867d855a0cd6e06e33d2422ae87d3 You have two json_agg(). Both are aggregates. For each nested aggregate you need a separate GROUP BY clause. That's what the error message says. Furthermore as already stated: I would avoid to mix up the JSON part and joining all other tables (see fiddle)

Comment: How would you suggest me to do it ? I'm completely new to jsonb thingy. Sorry to bother you so much ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198034/discussion-between-s-man-and-elisa-plessis).

Comment: Hey, which book would you recommend for me to understand postgesql better ?

Comment: Pew... it's really hard to answer this. First, i really don't know your current skills. Second, as far as I know there's no good book beyond beginner's knowledge (or administration books). Maybe Mastering Postgres published by Packt. Currently much better are numerous blogs. depesz, cybertec, jooq blog, postgresqltutorial.com and last but not least, the very good official postgresql documentation itself.